# Laravel Login page does nothing

Tags: laravel, logging

I am starting out with a project. I'm using de standard authorisation that comes with laravel. Registering a user works fine and it is logged in afterwards. I can also logout with no problem. The login screen seems fine. But when I enter my login credentials and click on 'login' nothing happens. no redirects or errors at all. It doesnt matter if I enter right, wrong or nothing at all in the login fields.

Here is my login.blade.php (default)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="Name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('username')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error 'type here'@extends('layouts.app') may be this is the issue , also try clearing cache.

> php artisan optimize:clear

Also set APP_DEBUG=true from the env file , to get error in logs.

Comment: Heyy Sublan "type here" line was mistakenly added here in stackover flow while i was trying to input my login.blade.php file;s code....and also i tried to cleared the cache and set the APP_DEBUG= true but same old problem is occuring.